# How to extract key infromation from G1 gc log

Tags: java, garbage-collection, overhead, utilization, g1gc

I find the G1 GC log to be somewhat cryptic and I wanted to ask can the log file itself be used to understand the total "stop the world" time for a specific time window that was used for GC?

Also , how is a full gc cycle specified for G1 collector?  I see a lot of GC pause(young) but nothing equivalent for a full GC.  Of course it could be because none has occurred yet but I can't say for sure.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

> I see a lot of GC pause(young) but nothing equivalent for a full GC

Full GCs should ideally never occur in G1 and it will try to perform mixed collections (young regions + a few old regions) instead, they'll show up as something like `[GC pause (mixed), ...]`

A full GC will also state its cause `[Full GC (Allocation Failure), ...]`

> I wanted to ask can the log file itself be used to understand the total "stop the world" time for a specific time window that was used for GC?

You can try [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) to visualize the logs. Although it won't give you a fine-grained breakdown of what exactly is happening during STW, for that you'll need to read the verbose logs, which are explained [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/understanding_g1_gc_logs)

Comment: Thank you for the tip , I will try to use GCViewer.  On a different note I am noticing one to two young generation collections per second.  Is that excessive? What would be a normal young generation collection rate for a JVM?  Thanks, Bob

Comment: Also, does anyone know if the VisualGC plugin of VisualVM also spit out the total "stop-the-world" time?